# PHP XML failing

Tags: php, xml, url, html-table

I know my code is messy, I am very new to this  and am learning as I go.

My site is this: http://itsalllegit.com (currently running off my home computer and using the tvdb api so its a bit slow at times).

Most of it appears to work, currently the only thing that doesn't is NCIS as shown here: http://itsalllegit.com/season.php?sid=72108&season=1.

I know its bad and long but here is my code... I'm stuck hard on this one and help would be greatly appreciated (so would any tips on making it better in general).

btw... if I `echo $url3` it comes up with `"(*#YR&(^#R(@$#%$&^@#%$*@#%$&^@$#&"` and so on.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Saars - Homepage</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />
    </head> 
        <body>
            <?php

                $series_id = $_GET["sid"];
                $season_number = $_GET["season"];
                $local_path = "images/Banner/".$series_id."-Banner.jpg";
                $url1 = file_get_contents("http://thetvdb.com/api/E676DF9578EF38D7/series/".urlencode($series_id));
                $xml = simplexml_load_string($url1);
                $series_name = $xml->Series[0]->SeriesName;
                $series_rating = $xml->Series[0]->Rating;
                $series_network = $xml->Series[0]->Network;
                $series_status = $xml->Series[0]->Status;
                    echo '<img src="'.$local_path.'"><br />';
                    echo "Name: ".$series_name."<br />";
                    echo "Rating: ".$series_rating."<br />";
                    echo "Network: ".$series_network."<br />";
                    echo "Status: ".$series_status."<br />";
                    echo "<hr />";
                        echo '<table bgcolor="#000000">';
                            echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td width="30">';
                                    echo '<font color="white">#</font>';
                                echo '</td>';
                                echo '<td width="500">';
                                    echo '<font color="white">Episode Name</font>';
                                echo "</td>\n";
                                echo '<td width="100">';
                                    echo '<font color="white">First Aired</font>';
                                echo "</td>\n";
                            echo "</tr>\n";
                        echo "</table>";
                for ($episode_number = 1; $episode_number <= 200; $episode_number++) {
                    $url2 = "http://thetvdb.com/api/E676DF9578EF38D7/series/".$series_id."/default/".urlencode($season_number)."/".urlencode($episode_number)."/en.xml";
                    $handle = @fopen($url2, 'r');
                    if ($handle === false) {
                        return;
                    } else {
                        $url3 = file_get_contents("http://thetvdb.com/api/E676DF9578EF38D7/series/".$series_id."/default/".urlencode($season_number)."/".urlencode($episode_number)."/en.xml");
                        $xml = simplexml_load_string($url3);
                        $episode_name = $xml->Episode[0]->EpisodeName;
                        $episode_rating = $xml->Episode[0]->Rating;
                        $episode_firstaired = $xml->Episode[0]->FirstAired;
                        $episode_overview = $xml->Episode[0]->Overview;
                        $column1 = '<a href="episode.php?sid='.$series_id.'&season='.$season_number.'&episode='.$episode_number.'">'.$episode_number.'</a>';
                        $column2 = '<a href="episode.php?sid='.$series_id.'&season='.$season_number.'&episode='.$episode_number.'">'.$episode_name.'</a>';
                        $column3 = '<a href="episode.php?sid='.$series_id.'&season='.$season_number.'&episode='.$episode_number.'">'.$episode_firstaired.'</a>';
                            echo '<table>';
                                echo "<tr>\n";
                                    echo '<td width="30">';
                                        echo $column1;
                                    echo "</td>\n";
                                    echo '<td width="500">';
                                        echo $column2;
                                    echo "</td>\n";
                                    echo '<td width="100">';
                                        echo $column3;
                                    echo "</td>\n";
                                echo "</tr>\n";
                            echo "</table>";
                    fclose($handle);
                    }
                }
                ?>
        </Body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening each URL twice but only reading the data once. The server may rejecting this behaviour as slamming and rejecting the second connection after a while. Try changing the contents of the loop to this:

```
// Define the URL
$url2 = "http://thetvdb.com/api/E676DF9578EF38D7/series/$series_id/default/".urlencode($season_number)."/".urlencode($episode_number)."/en.xml";

// Try and fetch the XML
// You are returning a value - are you in a function? Should you maybe break; instead?
if (!$xmlStr = file_get_contents($url2)) return FALSE;
if (!$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr)) return FALSE;

// Get data
$episode_name = $xml->Episode[0]->EpisodeName;
$episode_rating = $xml->Episode[0]->Rating;
$episode_firstaired = $xml->Episode[0]->FirstAired;
$episode_overview = $xml->Episode[0]->Overview;

// Output HTML
// A single-row table per record? Maybe you should have one table with multiple rows?
$epURL = htmlspecialchars("episode.php?sid=$series_id&season=$season_number&episode=$episode_number");
echo "
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width='30'><a href='$epURL'>$episode_number</a></td>
    <td width='500'><a href='$epURL'>$episode_name</a></td>
    <td width='100'><a href='$epURL'>$episode_firstaired</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>";
```

If it still doesn't work, try echoing out `$url2` in the loop to see what it contains when you get the errors.

Comment: thanks, will do, but i dont expect that it will help much because so far it only appears to be NCIS thats failing

Comment: I know that does seem odd, but when I load the URL you should be generating with your code (the first one that doesn't work when I loaded the page was ep 3: http://thetvdb.com/api/E676DF9578EF38D7/series/72108/default/1/3/en.xml) in a browser it works.

Comment: i know... sometime is works, sometimes it doesnt. i think i might put an if statement in that downloads it if not already local

Comment: it would definitely be worth implementing some form of caching, but you will also need to garbage-collect it, so you don't end up with a load of cached stuff that never gets used.